# openssl s_client -connect: 20 error with server signed certificate for client

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate

## What I want

I want to connect to a server using a given signed certificate (by the company running the server)

## What I have

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- My key and CSR files
- A signed certificate. It was signed by the people running the server I want to connect to (not a globally trusted CA) after I sent them my self generated CSR
- The `RootCA.crt` and the `CompanyCA.crt`

## What works

I can create a java keystore from the signed certificate and my key. If I use that in SoapUI, I can successfully connect to the server sending SOAP requests and get proper responses

## What doesn't work

I cannot use my certificate and key with `openssl s_client -connect`. The response is a `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)`

My request:

```
openssl s_client -connect service.company.com:443 -cert myCert.crt -key myKey.key
```

## What else did I try (to no avail)

- Using RootCA or CompanyCA with `-CAfile`
- concatenating RootCA and CompanyCA and use that with `-CAfile`
- Putting RootCA and CompanyCA in a directory and after doing `c_rehash` specifying it with `-CApath`
- Installing RootCA and CompanyCA in `/usr/lib/ssl/certs/` and doing `c_rehash`
- Creating a `.pem` from my certificate and key file (from `.p12`) and using that as `-cert`
- When I do `openssl verify -CAfile RootCA.crt CompanyCA.crt` the result is `error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate`
- When I do `openssl verify -CAfile RootCA.crt myCert.crt` the result is `error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate`
- When I do `openssl verify -CAfile RootCA.crt myCert.crt` the result is `error 2 at 1 depth lookup:unable to get issuer certificate`

I always get (pretty much)

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = DE, O = Company, CN = Company CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=DE/ST=City/L=City/O=Company/CN=service.company.com
   i:/C=DE/O=Company/CN=Company CA
 1 s:/C=DE/O=Company/CN=Company CA
   i:/C=DE/O=Other Company/OU=INST/DSW/CN=Other Company Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<SNIP>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=DE/ST=City/L=City/O=Company/CN=service.company.com
issuer=/C=DE/O=Company/CN=Company CA
---
Acceptable client certificate CA names
/C=DE/O=Other Company/OU=INST/DSW/CN=Other Company Root CA
/C=DE/O=Company/CN=Company CA 
---
SSL handshake has read 3926 bytes and written 2631 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported  
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA 
    Session-ID: SessionId
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: MasterKey
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket:
    <SNIP>
    Start Time: 1393503573
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Comment: Solved: The RootCA.crt file was wrong.

The company resent RootCA and CompanyCA files and now it works with the new files.

Comment: I should have known when `openssl verify -CAfile RootCA.crt CompanyCA.crt` returned an error. Now I can concatenate RootCA and CompanyCA and pass it as `-CAfile` to the connect command (and `-cert myCert.crt -key myCert.key`)